How to create a custom fetch plugin with a method wrapper in Nuxt 3?
I'm migrating a Nuxt 2 application to Nuxt 3 (Vue2 to Vue3 as well) and I used to use Axios library in my old application but now Vue 3 has its own internal fetch to make HTTP requests so Axios library for Nuxt 3 is not supported anymore. I followed the documentation on how to create a custom fetch function and it's working fine but I want to add a wrapper around it to make it work in a similar way as it used to with Axios. Currently I'm making my requests like this:
const resp = await useAPI(`/user/${url}`, {method: "POST", body: data})

I would like to call my composable like this:
const resp = await useAPI.post(`/user/${url}`, data, {/*any additional header*/})

I can't grasp my head around how to wrap the plugin for it to work this way, here's my customFetch plugin and my composable
customFetch plugin
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {

  const token = useCookie('token')

  const api = $fetch.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3012",
    onRequest({ request, options, error }) {
      if (token.value) {
        const headers = options.headers ||= {}
        if (Array.isArray(headers)) {
          headers.push(['Authorization', `Bearer ${token.value}`])
        } else if (headers instanceof Headers) {
          headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.value}`)
        } else {
          headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token.value}`
        }
      }
    },
    async onResponseError({ response }) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        await nuxtApp.runWithContext(() => navigateTo('/login'))
      }
    }
  })

  // Expose to useNuxtApp().$api
  return {
    provide: {
      api
    }
  }
})

useAPI composable
import type { UseFetchOptions } from 'nuxt/app'

export function useAPI<T>(
  url: string | (() => string),
  options: UseFetchOptions<T> = {},
) {
  return useFetch(url, {
    ...options,
    $fetch: useNuxtApp().$api as any
  })
}


having the same problem but i also have the error with this code "Cannot redefine property: $api". How did you solve it?

I was able to replicate this in Vue 3 exporting a function that returns a dictionary of functions, it's not exactly the same but I wasn't able to do it differently
import type { UseFetchOptions } from 'nuxt/app'

export function useAPI<T>() {
  return {
    get: async ( url: string | (() => string), headers:any = {})   => {
      return useFetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers
        $fetch: useNuxtApp().$api as any
      })
    }
    post: async ( url: string | (() => string), body: any = {}, headers:any = {})   => {
      return useFetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: body,
        headers: headers
        $fetch: useNuxtApp().$api as any
      })

    // any other http call
  }
}

And use the composable like this:
const resp = await useAPI().post(`/user/${url}`, data, {/*any additional header*/}

